# I need to shorten a char[]. I just want to get rid of the first letter

Tags: java

I need to shorten my char[] by one letter each time I pass through the code. The arguments I'm using are hello and hel. It should return true false false. At least that's what I think it should return.  I think what I have so far is close:

```
private void doDountSubStringMatchRecursive(String target, String key){
    char[] targetChar= target.toCharArray();//long one
    char[] keyChar= key.toCharArray();//short one
    for (int i = 0; i <=targetChar.length- keyChar.length; i++ ){
        System.out.println(testHelper(targetChar , keyChar));
        String recursive = targetChar.toString(); //Turns into a string
        targetChar = recursive.substring(1).toCharArray();//moves my string starting point over by one and converts the char[]
        System.out.println(targetChar.toString() + "  " +  keyChar.toString() );
    }
}


private boolean testHelper(char[] targetChar , char[] keyChar){
    boolean test = false;

    for (int i=0; i <= keyChar.length - 1; i++){ // runs through the char[] and states the test         
        if (keyChar[i] == targetChar[i]) {
            test =  true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return test;

}
```

And this is my output:

```
true
[C@24c21495  [C@41d5550d
false
[C@1cc2ea3f  [C@41d5550d
false
[C@40a0dcd9  [C@41d5550d
false
[C@1034bb5  [C@41d5550d
false
[C@7f5f5897  [C@41d5550d
false
[C@4cb162d5  [C@41d5550d
false
[C@11cfb549  [C@41d5550d
false
[C@5b86d4c1  [C@41d5550d
false
[C@70f9f9d8  [C@41d5550d
```

I don't get what this is doing now. And yes I know I could just find occurrence of the key by using indexof(key).

Comment: can you explain what your code is trying to do, we might come up with better suggestion

Comment: Ultimatly I'm trying to look for a substring of a big string. Ex. The big string would be 'atgacatgcacaagtatgcat' and I'd be looking for 'agt'. I want to go trough the list and find all the occurrence. But i want to do it in a recursive manner. so 'atgacatgcacaagtatgcat' turns in to 'tgacatgcacaagtatgcat' then 'gacatgcacaagtatgcat'. You get the idea.

Comment: why not to use `indexOf(String)` & `indexOf(String, int)` ?

Comment: I'm going through the online course and MIT OpenCourseWare. They want it in a recursive manner and I didn't know how to just get rid of one letter off the front so I figured I would just write my own code. In python they have a pretty easy way of doing it but that's not the case with Java.

Comment: So why did I get a minus one for asking this question? Do you guys know?

Comment: well its pretty easy in java too.. read the below answers

Comment: some one thinks that your question isn't helpful and doesn't make sense and so the downvote. you can make it clearly explaining by editting your comment into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what your code is supposed to do, as you haven't really stated the problem very clearly. However, there is one bug that you should fix right away:

```
targetChar.toString()
```

does not do what you think it does. It gives you the String representation of the char array object (which is something like "C@24c21495"), **not** an interpretation of that array as a sequence of characters. If you want a `String` representing the sequence of characters in the array, then you want to call

```
String.valueOf(targetChar)
```

or

```
new String(targetChar)
```

to convert the `char[]` into a more helpful `String`.

This change might help you debug the rest of your code.

Comment: This helped a bit with the output. However I still have the a problem with targetChar. Here is my output this time around: C@3d4b7453  hel. That's only one of them. It's weird that one works and the other doesn't I copy and pasted what you had to both of them.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. That worked. and changing that made the code work the way it needs to. Should I change the code to reflect the right answer if anyone else has this problem?

Comment: No, it's probably best to leave it as it is. Otherwise the answer won't make any sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in java, `array.toString()` is useless; you must use `Arrays.toString(array)`. Change your code to this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(targetChar) + "  " +  Arrays.toString(keyChar) );
```

FYI, Josh Bloch considers this a big mistake in java. I agree.